# How to add attributes to Google Dataflow PubSubIO Write

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a scenario to subscribe from Pubsub topic, read payload and publish it back to another PubSub topic with additional attribute based on the payload. Couldn't find any samples for populating custom attributes. Can someone help with the options or sample.

pipeline
.apply(
"Read PubSub Events",
PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription()))
.apply("Write PubSub Events", PubsubIO.writeMessages().to(options.getOutputTopic()));

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go!

```
    final List<String> elements = Arrays.asList(
            //Name, Product,Epoch time millis
            "Robert, TV, 1613141590000",
            "Maria, Phone, 1612718280000",
            "Juan, Laptop, 1611618000000",
            "Rebeca, Videogame, 1610000000000"
    );

    p
            .apply(Create.of(elements))
            .apply("to PubSubMessage", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, PubsubMessage>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                    String[] columns = c.element().split(", ");

                    HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    attributes.put("timestamp", columns[2]);
                    attributes.put("buyer", columns[0]);

                    PubsubMessage message = new PubsubMessage(c.element().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), attributes);

                    c.output(message);
                }
            }))
            .apply(PubsubIO.writeMessages().to(options.getTopic()));
```

Comment: Thanks @Iñigo for the answer. I have one more query, how do we handle errors when pubsub write message fails. Is it something you can help?

Comment: PubsubIO doesn't have any option to handle errors in it as BigQueryIO does (to add dead letter branches). Anyhow, erros while publishing should be rare and transient and Dataflow would retry them automatically (note that PubSub is special in Dataflow and the publishing happens on the backend side, called Windmill). If this helps, please consider accepting the answer so other users know is right